# ASP.Net Razor Identity

Tags: asp.net, razor, identity

I am almost new to ASP.Net razor pages. Just one problem
I created a Visual studio project recently but I cant seem to find the pages
for Identity (Login, Create account etc)

Can someone pls tell me where they went or whatever.

I would really appriciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a .NET core or .NET 5/6 project then the Razor pages for Identity are in the DLL.

If you wish to customise these pages then you have to scaffold the Identity UI pages. This MS documentation should provide the steps to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Ok thanks for the Help!